# 2 players, pion move in a matrix

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

I have a question related to 2 players move in a matrix. I assume that there is a well known method for this question, but I didnt find one.

There is a matrix with m rows, n columns. 2 players will move a pion respectively. **Pion can move only i+1 or j+1 which means only right or down.** Last row and last column of the matrix is filled with given values. **The purpose of the game is to reach last row or last column,** first player wants to get max value, second player wants to get lowest value, in the last row/column.

[image]

According to above table, 2 players will move pion p from 0,0 position. First player wants to reach a bigger element, while second player wants to reach a smaller element.

**My idea:**
Since players will move the pion respectively, I have separated the table as follows
[image]

cells with 1s refer the only possible moves of first player and 2s refer to only possible second player moves. From this point I thought about a dynamic programming solution but couldnt find any.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of dynamic programming is (number of row, number of column). The value is the best score the player can achieve by moving from this cell.
Base case: the score for a cell in the last row/column is fixed.
Inductive case: try to move right and down and choose the best option.

Comment: So in every move, player will move the pion to best position for himself for the current row/column value, did I understand right?

Comment: @Alin Yes, the goal of the player is to achieve the best score. That's why he always chooses the best among 2 options.